# Browserify builds stopped all return error on process.versions.node

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I have been seeing a recurring error with my browserify builds. It seems to be affecting all of my builds (I have old state that preserves them, but when I clone onto a new machine I get the error). I am using the the `babelify` transform as well. My specific command is:

`browserify <file> -t babelify -o <output>`

Each build completes successfully but I get the same error when in the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (core.js:1)
    at Object.319../core.json (core.js:23)
    at s (_prelude.js:1)
    at _prelude.js:1
    at Object.315../lib/async (index.js:1)
    at s (_prelude.js:1)
    at _prelude.js:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (run-filter.js:6)
    at Object.146._process (run-filter.js:44)
    at s (_prelude.js:1)
```

The specific line in `core.js` is:

`var current = process.versions.node.split('.');`

I have not been able to find any info on this error anywhere as problems with `split` not being defined return a variety of errors not related to browserify or any other tech I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is occurring in the [resolve module](https://github.com/substack/node-resolve/blob/master/lib/core.js#L1). [This commit](https://github.com/substack/node-resolve/commit/c2cbdddcc2aa1c427ccd8a7c1784c745093f836f) uses a node-specific version check, breaking the code in the browser environment. You must have the old version of resolve on your existing machine that doesn't have this bug. I've created [this issue](https://github.com/substack/node-resolve/issues/120) to track the bug's resolution.

Comment: Your code will work now on fresh npm installs. This commit fixed the issue: https://github.com/substack/node-resolve/commit/6739500f9632fbf5ce2e937ed85266ea2805fdbf

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This command fixed it: `npm install resolve`