# Undefined split in index.js and throw error in webpack bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, webpack

Hi everyone i just enccounter a weird reactJS error while building my project alert error message prom after adding "child_process": false into falback of webpack.config.js to fix the error child_process undefined:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLNAi.png)

and another error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWkRt.png)
locate in index.js in node_modules > nodemon > lib > utils > index.js
and in webpack folder

It seem to occur at line with the context of using split for undefined value i think

```
    var noop = function () { };
    var path = require('path');
    const semver = require('semver');
    var version = process.versions.node.split('.') || [null, null, null];
```

At first i try to debug by simply delete process.versions.node.split('.')

result into change:

```
    var version = [null, null, null];
    var version = [0, 0, 0];
```

2 post having the similar error that i follow is
[post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320950/typeerror-cannot-read-property-split-of-undefined-in-nodejs-nodemon)

[post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217146/browserify-builds-stopped-all-return-error-on-process-versions-node)

I try according to [issue #120](https://github.com/browserify/resolve/commit/6739500f9632fbf5ce2e937ed85266ea2805fdbf)

```
    var version = process.version.node.split('.') || [null, null, null]; //post 1
    var current = process.versions && process.versions.node && process.versions.node.split('.') || 
    []; //post 2
```

i noticed that the browser (Chrome) still alert error in it system as

```
    var version = process.versions.node.split('.') || [null, null, null];
```

After that i ask copilot and GPT, they said that my application was being poorly configure lead to let my webpack.config.js modified my nodemone (i use CRA to create project) and should include

```
    externals: {
      nodemon: 'nodemon'
    },
```

in module.exports in webpack.config.js to tell webpack to not modify the nodemon.

but again nothing much change. I didn't try npm install resolve because i believe that my problem didn't come from resolve because i did debug webpack breaking change error "Undefinded fs" by adding fallback fs: false but i will try if you guys think other wise